# How to "lock" a record from being updated or deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, locking

I have a model `User` which automatically has a `Task` generated.

I want to lock this task from editing or deleting.

What kind of modifications to my controller do I need to make?  Is there an elegant solution, or do I need to check every time there's an edit/destroy if it's the task in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no elegant solution as far as I am aware, you would have to check every time in the controller, but this is simple by defining this method in your controller:

```
def find_task
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  if @task.locked?
    flash[:error] = "This task is locked and cannot be altered at this stage."
    redirect_to tasks_path and return
  end
end
```

Then you can call this method as a `before_filter` for those actions you care about. By returning `nil` (that's what `return` does), the `before_filter` will halt and the action will not be executed.

Comment: What about moving the check (or having an "zomg don't update it" guard) to the model and using validation that route?

Comment: @pst: I did it in the controller as that would be where you could show  a flash error and redirect out. However, you could get the model to raise a custom `ProtectedRecord` error and then catch that in the controller. Sure.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a validation to do this quite nicely.

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :locked_cannot_be_modified

  private

  def locked_cannot_be_modified
    errors.add(:base, "Entry is locked") if changes.any? && whatever_logic_makes_it_locked
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you can implement readonly? on the model:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  def readonly?
    whatever_logic_makes_it_locked || super
  end
end
```

this approach will raise an exception instead of a validation error.  I guess it depends on what you're trying to do as to which approach is better.